# How to Constantly Apply a Force to a Rigidbody Within a Coroutine?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

For my game, I am trying to write an enemy behavior script, where the enemy walks forward for 1 second, then stands still for 1 second, then walks forward, stands still, etc. To implement this, I have written the following code:

```
bool isWandering = false;

void FixedUpdate
{
    if (!isWandering)
    {
        isWandering = true;
        StartCoroutine(Wander());
    }
}

IEnumerator Wander()
{
    Debug.Log("wandering");
    EnemyRB.velocity = new Vector2(walkSpeed * walkDir, EnemyRB.velocity.y);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    Debug.Log("waiting");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    isWandering = false;
}
```

For the most part, this seems to be working. The issue however, is that whenever the enemy moves forward, it moves for an extremely brief period before stopping. I have tried to increase the number of seconds it is supposed to walk, but it doesn't seem to make it walk for any longer than before.

How might I go about applying the force to the enemy's rigidbody for the entirety of the 1 second window? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep setting the velocity every physics tick until the one second has elapsed.

```cs
IEnumerator Wander() {
    Debug.Log("wandering");

    var wait = new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    for (float t = 0; t < 1f; t += Time.deltaTime) {
         EnemyRB.velocity = new Vector2(walkSpeed * walkDir, EnemyRB.velocity.y);

         yield return wait;
    }

    Debug.Log("waiting");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    isWandering = false;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I feel a wee bit dumb for not figuring that out myself.